# How can i add new colum in existing table as a foreign in laravel 9

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-8, laravel-blade, laravel-eloquent-resource

I was trying to add a new column as a foriegn key in existing table in laravel 9. But, it continuously giving SQL error. I want to create a simple `category_id` as a `foreign_key` in brand table.

The below code doesn't work,

```
$table->integer('category_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->after('password');
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('SET NULL');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `category_id` must be of big integer type
or
create user column like this

`$table->unsignedBigInteger('device_id')->index()->nullable();`

and
if your table exist create new migration class and alter table to add new column in your table

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$table->foreignId('category_id')->after('password');
$table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('SET NULL');
```

See more about [DB Column Types](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/migrations#available-column-types).